# How to make the updated contents get published in the Android App

Tags: android

I have an Android App development for story Maker.

The very first time Registered  user logged in our app and create the story and download an apk .

He now uploaded the apk file in  play store

The end user download the story now.

When the Registered user logged again updating his App with one more story.

This time he will not upload the app into play store Google.

I want how to update the new contents to the end user from registered user without uploading the App?

If we are going to save the content in server and serve to the end user  then what is the process to do this and what are the possible way to do this ?

Comment: why are you re-uploading the apk over and over again?

Comment: Actually the first app will create an apk for the registed users,my app is an app Maker

Comment: app  maker that is interesting, so every time a change is detected it re-upload the change? am i mistaken

Comment: yeah it's correct ,now your understanding is correct

Comment: Is there any way it will get syn with Google play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a combination of real time messaging, and notifications. Create a server(node or php) that maintains a state listener ,this state listener as hook to any connected device(android or ios). Whenever user performs a subscribed action such as (When the Registered user logged again updating his App) use real time communication to relay this to the server that watches your changes.(Use socket.io or lightStreamer even crossbar.io is perfect). Then intercept those changes with static notifications for every update received, Use fcm(fire-base cloud messaging) this way every data will be always be delivered and synced between clients accordingly.

```
This is light Streamer.
```

Optimized data streaming for web and mobile.
Lightstreamer enables several forms of real-time messaging. It is flexible enough to be used in any scenario, including mission critical applications.
►   Real-time Data Push and WebSockets
►   In-App Messaging and Push Notifications
►   Pub-sub with fan-out broadcasting and one-to-one messaging
►   Firewall and proxy friendly
►   Adaptive bandwidth throttling

```
This is socket.io
```

Socket.IO enables real-time bidirectional event-based communication. It works on every platform, browser or device, focusing equally on reliability and speed. Socket.IO is built on top of the WebSockets API(Client side) and Node.js.

```
This is crossbar.io
```

Crossbar.io is a networking platform for distributed and microservice applications, implementing the open Web Application Messaging Protocol (WAMP). It is feature rich, scalable, robust and secure. Let Crossbar.io take care of the hard parts of messaging so you can focus on your app's features.

```
This is firebase cloud Messaging.
```

Using FCM, you can notify a client app that new email or other data is available to sync. You can send notification messages to drive user reengagement and retention. For use cases such as instant messaging.

All the aforementioned is primarily based on javascript.For php consider this library instead.

```
This PHP Ratchet.
```

Ratchet is a loosely coupled PHP library providing developers with tools to create real time, bi-directional applications between clients and servers over WebSockets.

In gerneral, `WebSockets` is an advanced technology that makes it possible to open an interactive communication session between client and a server. With this API, you can send messages to a server and receive event-driven responses without having to poll the server for a reply.

Happy Coding @.

Comment: the db will maintain your logic for updating the end user.

Comment: Thanks it will help me lot and soon I will release the app @Caspaim Caldions

Comment: yea so basically maintain state list, update the state list when the user, he very first time Registered user logged in our app and create the story and download an apk , store that information, then if a new user logs in, and not equal to the one that stored just fire a event. with your pre determined logic.